# Java - Create grid of buttons with array, all with unique ID

Tags: java, arrays, javafx

I am making a game-board which requires a grid of buttons. I have a method where I can put in the width and height of the board and draw it like this:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < gameBoardWidth; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < gameBoardHeight; j++) {
                gameLayout.add(tiles[j], j, i);

            }
        }
```

The code above works perfectly fine but the problem is, I have an array of buttons. the size of the array is equal to the width * height, Each button within that array needs to have a unique ID incremented from 1 to *n*. Previously I made the board with this method

```java
for(int i = 0; i < gameBoardDimension; i++) {
            tiles[i] = new Button("");
            tiles[i].setMinSize(gameButtonWidth, gameButtonHeight);
            tiles[i].setId(Integer.toString(i));

            Button btn = tiles[i];
            btn.setOnAction(e -> {
                turn = 1;
                int ID = Integer.parseInt(btn.getId());
                setMove(ID, turn, btn);
                setAIMove();
            });
        }
```

But with the method above it is impossible to show them in a grid. How can I show the buttons in a grid so every button in the array has an ID of 1 to *n* with *n* being the size of the array?

Comment: `for (int row = 0; row < gameBoardHeight; row++) {
            for (int column = 0; column < gameBoardWidth; column++) {
                System.out.println("ID: " + ((row * gameBoardWidth) + column + 1));
            }
        }`

Comment: This may be expected behavior, but your loop suggests that you are ordering buttons top-down instead of left to right.

Comment: @Sedrick That loop works but I cant do `int id = ((row * gameBoardWidth) + column + 1))` and within the double for loop I do tiles[id]. It doesnt work and I get an InvocationTargetException

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an id as row (i) times width plus column (j) (plus 1 to start from 1 instead of 0) in the loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < gameBoardWidth; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < gameBoardHeight; j++) {
         Button b = new Button("");
         //... other stuff for button
         int id = i * gameBoardWidth + j + 1;
         b.setId(Integer.toString(id));

         //...
        }
    }
```

Comment: The I in my code must be from 1 to n,  So with every buttons added it will be tiles[0] = new button, tiles[1] = new button etc. I dont know if thats possible in a double for loop with also creating a grid

Comment: Why not create and add the buttons in the same loops you add tiles?